# PhoneGap Ajax request returning null

Tags: jquery, android, ajax, cordova

I am building an Android application with [PhoneGap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhoneGap), and [CodeIgniter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codeigniter#CodeIgniter) for the [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface). I am trying to make an Ajax request to the API to authenticate a user. The Ajax request is successful, but it does not return the JSON data. If I try the same API [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) in the browser I get the response back correctly.

```
$.ajax({
    url:auth_url,
    data:params,
    dataType:'jsonp',
    type:'get',
    success:function(data) {
        response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        alert(response);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus,errorThrown) {
        alert("Error status: " + textStatus);
        alert("Error type: " + errorThrown);
        alert("Error message: " + jqXHR.responeJSON);
    }
});
```

The success function alert the response as null. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: make sure auth_url is an IP address and not localhost

Comment: Great, I'll make it an official answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure auth_url is an IP address and not localhost.